# swagger java code gen hidden attributes

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

We are using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin to generate our model classes from spec file.

I know we can make a field hidden by using hidden=true in ApiModelProperty. Is there a way this can be set in the spec , so that codegen automatically adds hidden property to the field ?